# How to see detailled error message "Apple Mach -O Linker Error" in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, clang

I have only one error but I don't know what's exactly. I would like to see the exact Linker error message output in the std err in Xcode. How to do that in Xcode?

Comment: double check you library search path and libs in liker settings and remove duplicated and non exists libs

Answer (score 7):

Right-click the error message you described in Xcode, and choose the option "Reveal in Log". That displays the full error message.